# How to stop pirates? Someone already nulled and pirated my script :(

Tags: copy-protection, piracy

I dont know what to say. About 3 days ago I released a script to the public. Today I realised, after searching on google that someone had already nulled (removed my protection) and pirated the script.

How do I stop users from pirating the script? It is written in PHP.

Please help or suggest some solutions.

Thank you for your time.

**UPDATE** By releasing to the public means that I have started selling it to users.

**UPDATE** My program is priced at only $49. Very reasonable for the functionality it offers. I do not understand how I should stop pirates from pirating my code. The replies which most people have given are rather sarcastic. I was hoping for some good advice. I know there is no silver-bullet. But some techniques which you have used in your PHP programs.

Comment: You can't stop piracy.

Comment: If you release a script the public, and its useful, people are going to use it. Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see a problem here at all.

Comment: @Jon You can't stop floods, but you can make dams. You can't stop crime, but you can have cops & laws. You can't stop rain, but you can make umbrellas.

Comment: ...You can't stop piracy, but you can stew about it and produce ineffective countermeasures.

Comment: To earn a living you need to provide a service that your customers can't get elsewhere at a lower cost. Providing scripts is not generally one of these services, IMHO. Perhaps you might consider going the way of a number of companies that provide open-source software for free, but charge for support?

Comment: @mquander, "There is a time in the history of every invention that works, when it did not work yet". Giving up is sure as hell *not* the way to make progress.

Comment: @Alec Smart, I'm curious if you'd be willing to share with the community what this script/product is and what it does? Does it have a name?

Comment: @ Thomas Owens, @ Kieveli: Poor. I'd give -1 if it were possible. Here is one author who doesn't cripple his software with cumbersome "piracy countermeasures" but relied on the honesty of people, and not only does he get ripped off, you're also making fun of him to top it off. It's people like you that brought us crippleware, "product activation codes" and BS like that, many thanks.

Comment: Make it free. Try to get money out of them another way. Through support or plugins maybe. It's a shitty solution, but like the others have said you can't really stop them.

Comment: There's no simple way to prevent piracy.  Good long term solutions are 1) work faster and better than the pirates, so the genuine article will always be in demand, and 2) provide some value added, such as support and updates.

Comment: Nature intended programming to be free, I guess. Hence, we humans couldn't find a solution to curb piracy. OpenSourcing is a better model for us, programmers

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The only real way to prevent piracy is to not give the user the program at all! What I mean by this is have the logic you want to protect remain server side and offer a client interface.

There are a few companies that offer protection services, but these are expensive and can sometimes still be overcome.

If you're worried about this happening again, try obfuscating your code. [Here](http://www.raizlabs.com/software/phpobfuscator/) is a free program to do just that on PHP code.

Comment: I love the idea of making your code unreadable as a form of anti-piracy.  Remove all white-space, rename all variable and functions to random characters.  Basically, make the code so ugly that no one wants to use it.. haha

Comment: Bear in mind that obfuscation doesn't really accomplish anything. People hack binary machine code, and no obfuscator is going to be able to make your code harder to read than that.

Comment: Since it's written in PHP, you're already done half the job of obfuscation. (kidding, I'm sure there is some very good PHP out there. I just haven't seen it.)

Comment: I realize that obfuscation will not stop pirates. However, what it does do is raise the bar for reverse engineering. Any newbie can find a plain text password, key phrase, or jump in your binary, but if you obfuscate that same code, the person will need a higher level of skill to pirate your software. Even if some people still pirate it, it will cut down on the number of pirates.

I'll take 10 pirates rather than 100 any day. (Well unless I have ninjas to back me up)

Answer (score 18):

I'm not trying to be sarcastic here: forget about them. Here's my rationale:

- You can spend tons of time trying to
  prevent pirates from pirating your
  stuff, or you can spend the same
  amount of time giving your paying
  users more functionality.
- Extreme copy protection does not give your paying users anything but more
  hoops to jump through to use your
  application - which might lead them
  to get frustrated.
- Pirates will pirate your applications
  no matter how much time you spend
  trying to stop them.
- Budget a certain
  amount of time to put in basic copy
  protection - just enough to keep the
  honest people honest.
- Most importantly: Don't irritate your paying customers.
  They are the ones you need to make
  happy.

Answer (score 11):

There's not much you can do.

Be flattered your work was deemed worth the effort!

Comment: Downvote removed! I agree, its along the same lines as measuring hacking attempts as a sign of a successful web project.

Comment: If writing code is your profession, flattery doesn't put food on the table or keep a roof over your kid's heads.

Comment: (-1) Not that I don't agree with your sentiment, however what you've provided is a "comment" and not really an "Answer". By that I mean that saying "there's not much you can do" is not helpful to someone who is asking what you can do.

Comment: @David, I read that as "flattery doesn't put food over your kids' heads"... hm. That is all.

Comment: Every software developer should have the opportunity to put food on his family.

Comment: @devinb:  The problem is that there is no really effective technical solution, particularly for scripts.  You may lament this, or wish whole-heartedly that there was a solution, but there really isn't, and saying anything else is even less helpful.

Comment: I should have edited this further, but what I was driving at was that it's just a waste of time to try and combat this. Do just enough to keep honest people honest, and focus your efforts on supporting those customers. Then you'll have plenty of food to put on your family :)

Answer (score 7):

> How do I stop users from pirating the
>   script?

Do not release sensible source code to the public...

[**EDIT**] *After a few downvotes, I decided to comment on my answer:*

Any code that is released public has a chance of being hacked. This is the number one reason why Javascript is not secure. No matter how much you will obfuscate it, compress it or translate it to some random japanese dialect, it is still source code that the user has [access to](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/1843). Hence it should not contain any sensible information such as passwords or such. All sensible data should be stored in the server side where it is kept hidden from the user.

If you are releasing a php framework containing both the server and client code; then you have *no* way of *fully* protecting yourself. PHP is, like Javascript, an [interpreted language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language). You may translate it, compress it, or obfuscate it as much as you want, (and it's probably the best thing you can do) you will **never** fully protect it when released to the public.

Again... If there was a magic way to prevent code from being broken, it would have been known for a long time. No-cd patches / cracks for new games/softwares now are almost released the same day as the softwares themselves. It is, as noted by Paul, a form of flattery for you, even though I understand how sorry you may feel.

[There are a few instances where programmers ended up with bullet-proof protection, but it usually involved high-end engineering.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001125.html)

Comment: (-1) As programmers, we need to 'publish' our code to get paid.

Comment: > devinb : 'sensible' source code doesn't imply the entire source code. I have never seen published source code containing the author's password, db access information, or protection keys... Yet they usually get paid...

Comment: Do you think this author included his passwords and protection keys? Have you seen his source? But, as you added in your fantastic edit, it is very difficult to obfuscate interpreted languages *for the reasons you enumerated* (that's what makes it different from your initial answer... explanation). Good Job! (+1)

Answer (score 6):

With PHP, you're mostly out of luck. It's an interpreted language, which means that you are essentially forced to give away the source code. Sure, there are obfuscators (tools that "scramble" the source code to make it near impossible to read for humans), but they can be circumvented as well.

There are product like [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/) which seem to offer a better level of protection, but from my understanding, your customers need Zend Guard installed as well, which is almost never the case.

Answer (score 4):

There are several methods of handling this:

1. Offer your product as a service. This means finding appropriate hosting in the cloud, etc. This removes access to your code base, thus preventing direct piracy. Someone can still reverse engineer your stuff, but I'll touch on that later.
2. Add a unique identifier to each version of the script sold. This can be done automatically, and is great to do with obfuscated code (another, complementing method). This will give you the ability to track whoever pirated your code. If you can track them, you can sue them (or worse).
3. Pursue legal action. You'll need to know who leaked the code in the first place for this. Their PayPal information or even an IP address should be enough. You go to your lawyer, ask him to get a court order telling PayPal/ISP to release the identity of the thief, and then start tracking them down. If they're located overseas, your only real option is to freeze/appropriate funds from PayPal/credit card. Banks will be sympathetic only if they have a branch in your country (which can be targeted for legal action).
4. Ignore it, and simply build your business model around the support that you offer.

The sad fact is that information cannot be secured completely. There is no way to prevent a team of Indian programmers from reverse engineering your program. So you just have to be better than them, and constantly improve your product (this is "A Good Thing (TM)", so do it anyways)

Also keep in mind that DRM and other solutions are often controversial, and will reduce your sales (especially among early-adopters). On a personal level, I would suggest viewing this as a compliment. After all, your script was useful enough that someone bothered to pirate it within a week!

Answer (score 3):

PHP is easily decoded, so for people who really want to know, it's easy to find out the source code. However, there are certain obfuscator programs such as [this one](http://www.raizlabs.com/software/phpobfuscator/) that'll make your PHP script almost unreadable for those trying to decode it.

Comment: Obfuscation is security by obscurity. In other words, it's not security at all.

Comment: Yes, but there are usually lower hanging fruit.

Comment: But it will narrow the field of potential hackers down to a smaller group.

Answer (score 3):

What kind of protection did you think you had added to a PHP script, anyway? You should add a line of the form:

`if ($pirated)
  exit();`

and then make it mandatory (in the licence agreement) that users set the `$pirated` variable accordingly.

Comment: Pirates generally disregard license agreements though. By modifying the program, they break the usual 'no-tamper' clause.

Comment: :D  Under the DMCA, the licence agreement part is probably not even necessary: the anti-circumvention stuff should cover it!

Answer (score 3):

Forget trying to prevent it

Go the way of [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) (see sidebar on front page) and many other open source projects and ask for **donations**.

People actually do it!

Comment: Donations are not a viable business option.  If this is a hobby, that's fine.  If he's trying to create a business, he should go the SaaS route.

Answer (score 2):

Contact the pirate and let h{im,er} know that you will be forced to take legal action against them if they do not abide by the license.

Comment: You might try something more friendly first in less you actually can follow up on your threat. Something like "hi, I noticed you're using my program. It'd be really great if you bought a copy so I could feed my family. Here's a coupon! Thanks!"

Comment: @Idigas, While I wouldn't necessarily do what Michael is suggesting, Hackers are by their nature resentful of authority, so threatening them with a personal email could, and likely will, cause them to begin attacking you back.

Comment: And if the pirate is in <any-country-with-weak-copyright-laws>, he will laugh his a** off!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Michael.

Try ionCube or Zend Guard. They are both commercial offerings, but you say that you are selling your software so it might be worth it. Although nothing is foolproof and can be reverse engineered with enough effort and technical skill, these solutions are probably good enough for the average PHP script vendor.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Samoz's suggestion to keep the logic server side, however this can often be hard to do. The best strategy is to make the user want to buy it by offering updates automatically to registered users, as well as installation, advice and good support. You are never going to sway people hell bent on pirating, however your goal should be to persuade those who are undecided as to whether to pirate or purchase the script.

Any obfuscation/decryption technique for PHP can be cracked

Answer (score 1):

Jumping in very late to this conversation, but saw this question featured.  Nobody mentioned contacting a lawyer and pursuing litigation.  You likely saw the script on a server - hosted by a known hosting company - you can probably get a DMCA takedown to have the script removed.  If you really press the case, you may be able to sue for damages.

Found this link to assist in going this route:
http://www.keytlaw.com/Copyrights/cheese.htm

Answer (score 1):

You could always pirate it yourself to the internet and hope that any nuller will think "its already been grabbed" so don't bother. But pirate a real buggy version. When users come to you looking for help you'll know they have a pirate version if they question you about specific bugs you purposely added and you can approach them accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think it's easier to protect PHP scripts than desktop software, because with latter you never know who is running the cracked copy.

In case of PHP on the other hand, if people run your software on public web servers, you can easily find them and take them down. Just get a lawyer and turn them in to the police. They could also be breaking DMCA laws if they remove your protection so that gives you even more ammunition.

Technical way to protect your code is obfuscation. It basically makes your code unreadable like binaries in compiled languages (like Java). Of course reverse engineering is possible, but needs more work.

Answer (score 0):

If your script won't consume a lot of bandwidth, you could keep your "logic" server-side, as samoz suggested, but if your users won't use it responsively ( a crawler, for example ), this could be trouble.

On the other side, you could become a ninja ...

Answer (score 0):

Attach a copyright notice to it. Some companies will actually care that they're using software properly.

Answer (score 0):

In general it's hard to prevent users from stealing code when the program is written in a scripting language and distributed in plain text. I've found that http://feedafever.com/ did a really nice job of being able to sell PHP code but still give the code to users.

But the solution to your problem is very dependent on the domain of your program. Does this script run on the users machine with no internet connection? Or could this be a hosted service?

I'd also suggest looking at some of your favorite software, and seeing how they convinced you to pay for it initially. The issue I find isn't always "how can I prevent my users from stealing my software" but sometimes more "how do I convince my users that it's in their best interests to pay me". Software piracy often comes when your product is overpriced (Ask your friends what they would pay for a software package like the one you are selling, I've found that I have historically overpriced my software by 20%).

Anyway, I hope this helps. I'm glad that you are trying to create software that is useful to users and also not incredibly crippled. I personally of the mind that all software that isn't shrink wrapped or SAAS should be free, but I totally understand that we all need to eat.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is not to try to prevent the piracy (in the long term, this is a losing battle), but to make the legitimate version of your product more accessible and/or more functional than the pirate versions.

"Making it more functional" generally means providing involves additional features or services to registered users, which cannot be replicated for free by the pirates. This may be printed materials (a users manual, a gift voucher, etc), services such as telephone support or help setting the product up, or online extras within the software.

I'll point out that companies such as RedHat are able to make significant amounts of money selling open source software. The software itself is freely available -- you can download it and use it for free without paying RedHat a penny. But people still pay them for it. Why? Because of the extra services they offer.

"Making it more accessible" means making it easier to get your legitimate software than a pirate copy. If someone visits Google looking for your software and the first result is a pirate download site, they'll take the pirate copy. If the first result is your home page, they're more likely to buy it. This is especially important for low-cost software: pirated software may be 'free', but usually it takes more effort to get. If that effort is outweighed by the low cost and lack of effort of simply buying it legitimately, then you've won the battle.

Answer (score 0):

I saw anti-piracy working once only. Quantel EditBox systems (a post-processing video  solution), Hardware+Software+Internet solution against Piracy. Workstation only works after checking if the bank received the monthly rent. If not, workstation was locked. Funny days when this happens... (Funny days for me, no work at all... No funny day for the hacker.)
Well, PHP is far away from hardware solutions... so I guess your only real choice is a server side protected against a tiny unsafe client pushing content, as pointed in some answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

First be happy you have written something useful enough to be pirated. .

This is little consolation, but remember, most human beings are thieves (given the opportunity).

#### Courts

Lotta guys saying "hire a lawyer".

Those guys prob never worked for a lawyer or seen a case through from inception to closure. Plus they are assuming that the legal system is sweet. If you are in a highly corrupt country, like in India, or China, good luck to you. It will take forever just to get to the court. Very hard to find a good lawyer. Most lawyers there are barely literate. I've had the pleasure of dealing with six. Three seemed very good. Of the other three - one was essentially convicted of embezzlement, and the other two were essentially imbeciles. so it's very, very hit and miss. Like most things: if you want a good lawyer, it will cost you.

If you are in the US then the person with the deepest pockets will likely be victorious - but it is time consuming and expensive, and you may (not) get your money back.

"a bad settlement is better than a good law suit". the adage still holds true. don't even attempt it unless you have money and time you are happy to lose.

#### Preventing privacy

If your app can be thrown on the cloud, then do so:

- Put your code behind a server
- Do not release the code.
- Expose "endpoints". Allow users to submit inputs. and give them the output.

#### Application needs to be client facing

Now you are at risk.

- in this case, if possible give them an executable i.e. binary format. If you give them a .net dll, then even if you obfuscate that, you're still exposed because you're giving them IL code.
- remove and put a few key functions on the cloud (i.e. follow the above step). Now piracy is not as easy / straight forward. Pirates will have to replicate the cloud functions, which is a  pain. Perhaps make post requests to an online data store. many ways you can skin the cat but the principle is the same: make sure that there is some source code hidden in the cloud that cannot be easily replicated.
- Don't forget to charge for your services. If it's useful, people will be incentivised to pay for it.

Answer (score -1):

piracy != copyright infringement

There are known routes to litigate copyright infringers.

Does it really matter enough to hire a legal team?

Comment: Quoting Wikipedia: “For electronic and audio-visual media, unauthorized reproduction and distribution is also commonly referred to as piracy [...] The practice of labeling the act of infringement as "piracy" predates statutory copyright law.”

Answer (score -1):

Obfuscation do add something. It will not be fun to try to modify your code at least even if they can take the first version of it. In best case they will try to find some open source project that does something similar. Guess this would give you an fast fix at least for your problem?